# TFS locking Visual Studio 2013 by using 25% CPU usage

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, workspace

I'm using VS2013 with the built in TFS client and using a local workspace.

Whenever i start to edit a file the devenv.exe process suddenly starts to use 25% cpu usage and locks Visual Studio for up to a minute.

I've proven this is tfs doing this as when I unbind there's no problem at all.

I use a proxy server to download the files but the problem happens if the proxy is set or not in source control settings.

I've also tried using a server workspace but there's no difference.

In the Team Explorer settings I've disabled the portal settings.

Not sure what else to try and any advice would be appreciated.

[image: TFS settings]

Comment: Try to use Process Explorer to see what VS is actually doing while it locks.

Comment: Process explorer doesn't tell me anymore than task manager does when it locks. It simply shows the cpu usage as 25-30% for devenv.

Comment: Have you checked thread stack trace?

Comment: Hi and thanks. Yes and it shows the main the thread of devenv.exe+0x1c3e1 as using the cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Local Workspace performance starts to degrade at about 25k files in the workspace. This is dependant on the capabilities of your PC. This is why server workspaces still exist.

You can open the workspace and change it back to server in the UI. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx for how to do this an absolute max files...